# Custom adapter refresh in gridview android

Tags: android, gridview, getview

i have a grid view with 6 cells loading in adapter. when i click each cell,i am going to add image either from taking photos or choosing images from gallery.after selecting images, the grid view is showing empty only. though i set image in one cell,when go for another cell,the previous selection is gone. how to make it done?.. plea help me.  if i am anything wrong , please guide me.

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpc_document_view, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        if (fileList.size() == 0) {
            textView.setText(DOCUMENT_NAME_LIST[position].toString());
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_add_document);
            }
        } else {

            Bitmap bitmapResized = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                if (!fileList.get(i).equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("fileList here ,,,," + fileList.get(i).toString());
                    Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_add_document);
                    bitmapResized = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                } else {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(fileList.get(i));
                    bitmapResized = ImageRelatedStuff.convertURIToBitmap(selectedImageUri, mContext);

                    if (bitmapResized != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmapTemp = bitmapResized;
                        bitmapResized = null;
                        bitmapResized = ImageRelatedStuff.getResizedBitmap(bitmapTemp, 500, 500, 0);
                    }
                }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageRelatedStuff.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmapResized, 15));
            }
        }
    } else {
        grid = convertView;
        imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    grid = new View(mContext);
    grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpc_document_view, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
} else {
    grid = convertView;
    imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

}
if (fileList.size() == 0) {
        textView.setText(DOCUMENT_NAME_LIST[position].toString());
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_add_document);
        }
    } else {

        Bitmap bitmapResized = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            if (!fileList.get(i).equals("")) {
                System.out.println("fileList here ,,,," + fileList.get(i).toString());
                Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_add_document);
                bitmapResized = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            } else {
                Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(fileList.get(i));
                bitmapResized = ImageRelatedStuff.convertURIToBitmap(selectedImageUri, mContext);

                if (bitmapResized != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmapTemp = bitmapResized;
                    bitmapResized = null;
                    bitmapResized = ImageRelatedStuff.getResizedBitmap(bitmapTemp, 500, 500, 0);
                }
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageRelatedStuff.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmapResized, 15));
        }
    }
```

Problem is when your convertView is not equals null you are not setting anything image on imageView. That is why on 2nd cell where convertView is null you are getting image while on previous cell which is not null you are getting nothing.

Comment: Its not yet solved @ramesh.  when i chose one image from sd card,then all 6 cells are showing same image only. but my result is one the particular cell to be added that images and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final int GRID_COUNT = 6;

// you need an array save bitmap with position
Bitmap[] bitmapArray;

public MyAdapter(){
    bitmapArray = new Bitmap[GRID_COUNT];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        // inflater your layout
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    // get the bitmap in array by position
    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapArray[position];
    // when bitmap is null ,show default picture
    if (bitmap == null){
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
    }else{
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    return convertView;
}

// activity or fragment use this method call adapter refresh
public void setBitmap(int position, Bitmap bitmap){
    bitmapArray[position] = bitmap;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

update my answer, hope help you

Comment: no luck... same result again.. can u pls tell me what is the problem here?.. in my getcount method ,return value is always 6. but filesize is 1 whenever i chose a image from gallery..then y it is always looping 6 time though filesize is 1.

Comment: @saravanan the getCount() method should return fileList.size(), do you do that? when your fileList count changed, you must call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: s. but initially i should show empty image 6 icons on each 6 cells. i have to click each cell to put image. if i put filelist.size(), first time it will show only 1 cell,2nd time it will show only 2 cells....so on. how to make all 6 icons visble and also i should able to add images to each cell?.. can u get me ?.. pls help me..

Comment: @saravanan sorry, I know your meanings now, I update my answer, hope help you, my english is terrible

Comment: thanks for ur answer.. pls update me the answer once u know..thanks